# terminator - programmatic way to set window titles?

Tags: terminator

I use terminator and I know I can set the title through mouse or keystrokes; however, I'd like to use a script to do so.

Is this possible?

https://github.com/software-jessies-org/jessies/wiki/Terminator

Comment: Hmm, not quite, I want to set it while I'm still using the terminal - not just on initialization.  I guess, I could create a new instance each time I want to change it, but that doesn't sit well with me.

Comment: It looks like it should work at runtime - make it a function in your `.bashrc` if you don’t want to type the whole thing out every time

Comment: fair enough, I stumbled upon this earlier but only tried for the first 2 or 3 answers, this one works for me: set_title() { printf "\e]2;$*\a"; }